Defined a Set function to copy a variable-sized 2D square matrix but getting garbage
Specification:
Given: NxN Rmatrix.
Given: N, where N is 2 or 4.

Define a Set function that has access to Rmatrix and N.
The Set function copies the information into a class data member(s) for later use when calling the API.
Define a unit test print function using the stored class data members, Rmatrix, and N.
Call API using the stored class data members, Rmatrix, and N.

// ***** THE 3RD PARTY API ****  (cannot be changed)
void compute(const creal32_T R_data[], const int R_size[2],
             int* returnCode, int* stuff);  
// **returnCode** and **stuff** are outputs.

Below is my attempt, but I get mostly 0's. Here is the code that I was able to run after many build errors.
NOTICE that the API refers to creal32_T R_data[] whereas the test data refers to creal32_T R_data[4][4];  Two similar but different types were causing me to have build errors.
Array_3rd_Party_Inputs.hpp:
This part is just the test data from the third party for our unit test
I don't think I should include this section in my class wrapper around the 3rd party API (but if it is the only way to accomplish the goals, then I'll try to get a waiver).
#ifndef ARRAY_3RD_PARTY_INPUTS_HPP
#define ARRAY_3RD_PARTY_INPUTS_HPP
// This header file (and its data) comes from a 3rd party.
// NOTE: **** 3rd party is column-major ****

typedef int int32_T;

typedef struct
{
    float re;
    float im;
} creal32_T;

// The following struct provides input/output test data for unit tests.
// Shown are the inputs. Not shown are the outputs.
typedef struct Input_output_data_type
{
    struct Inputs
    {
      int rc;
      creal32_T R_data[4][4];
      int32_T R_size[2];
    } inputs;
} INPUT_OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE;

INPUT_OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE inputOutputData[2] =
{
  { 
    { // 2x2
      0,
      {
        { {111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2} }, // Col 1 -other two values in this row are {0+ 0i}
        { {333.0, 333.3}, {444.0, 444.4} }  // Col 2
      },
      {
        2, // R_size[0]
        2  // R_size[1]
      },
    }
  },
  {
    {  // 4x4
      0,
      {
        { {11.0, 11.1}, {12.0, 12.2}, {13.0, 13.3}, {14.0, 14.4} }, // Col 1
        { {21.0, 21.1}, {22.0, 22.2}, {23.0, 23.3}, {24.0, 24.4} }, // Col 2
        { {31.0, 31.1}, {32.0, 32.2}, {33.0, 33.3}, {34.0, 34.4} }, // Col 3
        { {41.0, 41.1}, {42.0, 42.2}, {43.0, 43.3}, {44.0, 44.4} }, // Col 4
      },
      {
        4, // R_size[0]
        4  // R_size[1]
      },
    }
  }
};

#endif // ARRAY_3RD_PARTY_INPUTS_HPP

Set2DArray.cpp:
#include "Array_3rd_Party_Inputs.hpp"

#include <iostream>

template<int N, typename T>
static void
PrintRMatrixInput(T& R)
{
  std::cout << "PrintRMatrixInput: N = " << N << ";  T is type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  for (int rr = 0; rr < N; ++rr)
  {
    for (int cc = 0; cc < N; ++cc)
    {
      std::cout << R[cc][rr].re << " + " << (R[cc][rr].im) << "i\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n\n";
}

struct ResultsXcorrMatrix // I created this struc to handle 2x2 and 4x4 matrix.
{
    union
        {
            creal32_T RMatrixData[16]{}; 
            creal32_T RMatrixData2[2][2];
            creal32_T RMatrixData4[4][4];
        };
};

class Matrix_Display_Class
{
public:
  Matrix_Display_Class() {}  // ctor
  
void SetRmatrix(creal32_T* rMatrix, int32_T rMatrixSize[2])
{
  inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData = rMatrix;
  inR_.rMatrixSize_ = rMatrixSize;
}

 struct InputXcorrMatrix
  {
    union
    {
      creal32_T* RMatrixData{};   // maybe: "creal32_T RMatrixData[16]{}"
      creal32_T RMatrixData2[2][2];
      creal32_T RMatrixData4[4][4];
    } rMatrix_{};
    int32_T* rMatrixSize_{};
  } inR_{};

};

int main()
{
    // ResultsXcorrMatrix res{};

    Matrix_Display_Class myDisp{};

    // ******** print out 2x2 Array **********
    
    INPUT_OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE* ioDataPtr = &inputOutputData[0];
    INPUT_OUTPUT_DATA_TYPE::Inputs ioDataInputs = ioDataPtr->inputs;

    std::cout << "\nEXPECTED THIS:" << std::endl;
    PrintRMatrixInput<2>(ioDataInputs.R_data);

    myDisp.SetRmatrix(ioDataInputs.R_data[0], ioDataInputs.R_size);

    std::cout << "BUT GOT THIS:" << std::endl;
    PrintRMatrixInput<2>(myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData2);

    // ******** print out 4x4 Array **********

    ioDataPtr = &inputOutputData[1];
    ioDataInputs = ioDataPtr->inputs;

    std::cout << "EXPECTED THIS:" << std::endl;
    PrintRMatrixInput<4>(ioDataInputs.R_data);

    std::cout << "BUT GOT THIS:" << std::endl;
    PrintRMatrixInput<4>(myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData4);

}  // END main

I tried examining memory addresses in VSCode, but got a confused. In the original program having this code, I stepped into SetRmatrix()and saw that inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData had the first struct members (i.e., .re and .im) fields set correctly. I thought that since RMatrixData2 should have the same address, then it would also have the correct values.
I tried different calling sequences such as using creal32_T rMatrix[4][4], but all my approaches led to compiler errors.
I tried a memcpy, but I did not like the ensuing segfault.
OUTPUT:
EXPECTED THIS:
PrintRMatrixInput: N = 2;  T is type: A4_A4_9creal32_T
111 + 111.1i    333 + 333.3i
222 + 222.2i    444 + 444.4i


BUT GOT THIS:
PrintRMatrixInput: N = 2;  T is type: A2_A2_9creal32_T
2.58476e-26 + 2.84464e-43i      0 + 0i
0 + 0i  0 + 0i


EXPECTED THIS:
PrintRMatrixInput: N = 4;  T is type: A4_A4_9creal32_T
11 + 11.1i      21 + 21.1i      31 + 31.1i      41 + 41.1i
12 + 12.2i      22 + 22.2i      32 + 32.2i      42 + 42.2i
13 + 13.3i      23 + 23.3i      33 + 33.3i      43 + 43.3i
14 + 14.4i      24 + 24.4i      34 + 34.4i      44 + 44.4i


BUT GOT THIS:
PrintRMatrixInput: N = 4;  T is type: A4_A4_9creal32_T
2.58476e-26 + 2.84464e-43i      0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i
0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i
0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i
0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i  0 + 0i


Type punning via union is UB.

you expect A4_A4_9creal32_T but then only 2x2 matrix elements? Typo?

why are you doing this? All your issues would go away if you would use a plain std::array<N,std::array<N,int> and no union, no aliasing. Is there some reason for making this complicated? If yes you should tell us.

Type punning a pointer to an array almost never works, even in a implementation-defined way. For many implementations you have &(myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData) == myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData4,  but you are expecting myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData==myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData4. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bKoY966TK. "I thought that since RMatrixData2 should have the same address". No it doesn't. It share the address of the pointer in typical implementations, not the value of the pointer. Anyway as already commented all these are UB per the standard.

Unsure what you want to do... struct Inputs is directly "usable" (you might add a void print(const Inputs&) similar to your PrintRMatrixInput (and you can even use size from the input ;-) ))

I simplified your code to that removing all union stuff

https://godbolt.org/z/6oPaqWzzs

I may not modify the Array_3rd_Party_Inputs.hpp file. In it, notice R_data is defined as a 4x4, but the matrix returned can be 4x4 or 2x2. And I thought that since std::array is fixed dimensions, I could not use it for a function that returns variable square matrix dimensions.

Simplifying the SetRmatrix function would be great. Its purpose is to set class data members with either the 2x2 or 4x4 matrix. Another function later will be called that uses the Rmatrix. In another 3rd party class, its function output returned the matrix that could be 2x2 or 4x4, and its dimensions. I used the union approach there to get correct unit tests. So, I thought the same union approach where the R matrix is an input would also work.

You need to show the signature and example usage of the 3rd-party function. Whenever you find that you need to write a lot to explain some code, [edit] to show the code directly instead.

@WeijunZhou I updated the OP to show the API function call.

Just use a std::vector and do the indexing manually. std::mdspan may be useful but the compiler support is still incomplete.

@WeijunZhou I added a more formal specification in the OP to clarify the issues I was having both in debug printing of the Rmatrix and the build errors.

std::mdspan- We just moved up to C++17.

From that signature void compute(const creal32_T R_data[], const int R_size[2], int* returnCode, int* stuff); I guess that R_data must be flattened matrix and R_size are the matrix dimensions. Do you have some documentation of this compute api? How does it interpret the elements, is elem(x, y) in the position R_data[y*R_Size[0] + x] ? If you know these details, you can write a Matrix class that will take your test data from [4][4] format, flatten it to std::vector<creal32_T> format, and expose creal32_T* to use with api (e.g. with return vec.data();).

@pptaszni Excellent point. API input/output table just noted the variable matrix size but nothing written about physical layout. The 3rd party writer told me that the 2x2 would not be contiguous in memory. Today the input validation function failed because the 2x2 was not flattened. I will have to get or write a class matrix packer to flatten out both the input and output test data for unit test comparisons.

From void compute(const creal32_T R_data[], const int R_size[2], int* returnCode, int* stuff);, I will say you have to call it compute(&ioDataInputs.R_data[0][0], ioDataInputs.R_size, &rc, &stuff); (I suppose that expected usage should be compute(ioDataInputs.R_data, ioDataInputs.R_size, &rc, &stuff); but types mismatch in C++

In OP: First row: { {111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2} }, is actually in memory:
{ {111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2} }, {0,0}, {0,0} ). So I don't see how std::array solves the problem. 3rd and 4th row are both: {{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}}. So for the 2x2 matrix in the 4x4 matrix, there are 4 elements set and 12 elements with all zeros.

Your direct issue is that in your setter you make RMatrixData an active member of an union:
inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData = rMatrix;

and the you attempt to do a type punning here (access to inactive member), which is undefined behavior.
PrintRMatrixInput<2>(myDisp.inR_.rMatrix_.RMatrixData2);

Also your ioDataInputs.R_data[0] points to the first row of data
{{111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2}, {0,0}, {0,0}},

so it would be wrong anyway.
Then, your underlying issue is that you are trying to use some weird C-style coding with C++. Get rid of all of your raw arrays T arr[x][y] and raw pointers, you can use std::array<T, N> instead (array of array is also an option). If you need complex numbers, just use std::complex. If you need a variant (I don't think you do), use std::variant, in general I don't see any reason to have unions in your code.

I may not modify the Array_3rd_Party_Inputs.hpp file. In it, notice R_data is defined as a 4x4, but the matrix returned can be 4x4 or 2x2. I don't know how to use std::array<T, N> for a single variable, since N can be 2 or 4, and std::array is for fixed size items. Can you please elaborate.

The purpose of the SetRmatrix function is to set a class data member with either the 2x2 or 4x4 matrix; there is also a size class data member function whose value will be set to either 2 or 4. The Rmatrix raw pointer later is an input to the 3rd party function. I wanted to be able to display the matrices (as done in the OP) to verify correct values.

Judging by template<int N I assumed that your N is a compile-time constant, if it's not, then use std::vector instead. Then, judging by class Matrix_Display_Class I assumed that you need a class that behaves like matrix, even if only for display purposes. The easiest way to start is to simply use std::array or std::vector to avoid C++ pitfalls around raw pointers and arrays. If I guessed wrong, then please explain the underlying problem in your question.

Having input data in T data[4][4] format is not a problem, you can just write a matrix constructor that accepts a raw pointer with dimensions, then copy the values to standard C++ containers.

Thank you for your advice. From the general comments, I realize that I had to make the issues I have more complete. I revised the OP. Please take a look. Thank you.

"your ioDataInputs.R_data[0] points to the first row of data so it would be wrong anyway.". Agreed that it is pointing to the first row of data. Why wrong? Inside a function it just decays to a pointer to the first element of 16 contiguous structs of the entire 4x4 matrix. Right?

Just to make sure we're on the same page: In OP: First row: { {111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2} }, is actually in memory:
{ {111.0, 111.1}, {222.0, 222.2} }, {0,0}, {0,0} ). So I don't see how std::array solves the problem. 3rd and 4th row are both: {{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}}. So for the 2x2 matrix in the 4x4 matrix, there are 4 elements set and 12 elements with all zeros. Since the 3rd party header used creal32_T, I did not use std::complex.

Actual solution for the 2x2 input matrix  was to copy the 4 elements from the 4x4 into a 2x2 matrix (deleted the union). But this is not part of this question so it is not an answer. I will look further into UB of the unions. Since the 3rd psrty API had all raw pointers, I kept that style. If there is something functional incorrect with the raw pointers, please advise.
